# Disabling the Submit button After one click using tagID

Tags: javascript, jsp, jsp-tags

The page should redirect to next page after clicking( Enter data only once in DB) the submit button once instead if the user clicks the submit button twice the data enters in Db for two entries .

Have disabled the submit button to avoid the multiple entries still the issue persisting

```
<netui:form action="login" method="post" onSubmit="return checkForm();" tagId="ckeckLogin">
        <table style="width: 100%;">
            <tr>
                <td  style="width: 45%;">
                    <div>
                        <table style="width:100%;" border="0">
                            <tr>
                            </tr>
                            <%  if (SiteInfo.isLocalhost(request)) { %>

<tr style="vertical-align:top;">
                                <td style="width:3%; white-space:nowrap;text-align: right;" class="right-align" id="loginForm.label.id"><i18n:getMessage messageName="portlets.label.pagecode.id"/>:</td>
                                <td class="left-align"><netui:textBox tagId="pageLookup_id" dataSource="actionForm.id" size="8" maxlength="25" style="text-transform: uppercase;"/><br/></td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td class="center-align" colspan="2">
                                    <netui:button type="reset" onClick="document.forms[getNetuiTagName('clearFrom', this)].submit();"><i18n:getMessage messageName="portlets.button.clear"/></netui:button>
  <!-- Submit button goes here --->   <netui:button type="submit"><i18n:getMessage messageName="portlets.button.login"/></netui:button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                               </table>
 </netui:form>
```

JavaScript:

```
  function checkForm()
        {
            var validateErrorReason = '';

            // reset the validation label errors
            document.getElementById('loginForm.label.id').className = '';

        var errorData = document.getElementById('submitResetRequestForm.errorData');

            if(!(validateErrorReason == '')) {
                errorData.innerHTML = '<i18n:getMessage messageName="error.form.highlight" />';
                return (false);
            }

//To Disable Submit button
document.getElementById('ckeckLogin').disabled = true;

            }
```

The submit button should disable after one click

Answer (score 0):

```html
<input type="submit" id="subBtn" value="Send" />

<button onclick="document.getElementById('subBtn').disabled = true;">True</button>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('subBtn').disabled = false;">False</button>
```

You have to assign an id to the submit button to get it from getElementById('id') and disable it.

Comment: <netui:button type="submit" id = "submitButton" > <i18n:getMessage messageName="portlets.button.login"/>   document.getElementById('submitButton').disabled = true  ;                                   
   Will this disable the Submit button

Comment: <netui:button type="submit" id = "submitButton" > <i18n:getMessage messageName="portlets.button.login"/</netui:button> document.getElementById('submitButton').disabled = true  ;                                   
@ Daniele Tentoni Will the above edit disable the Submit button